# mariadb-connector-cpp-1.0.1: Linking error for cjportedtests.exe

Tags: mariadb, linker-errors, undefined-reference

**Environment**

- Windows 10
- MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, 11.2.0
- cmake version 3.19.5

Error comes message as follows:

[ 74%] Linking CXX executable ..\cjportedtests.exe
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Libraries/mariadb/lib/libtest_framework.a(test_asserts.cpp.obj): in function `testsuite::assertEquals(sql::SQLString const&, char const*, char const*, int)': D:/Daten/Installation/Coding/mariadb/mariadb-connector-cpp-1.0.1-src/test/framework/test_asserts.cpp:298: undefined reference to` __imp__ZN3sqlneERKNS_9SQLStringEPKc'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [test\CJUnitTestsPort\CMakeFiles\CJUnitTestsPort.dir\build.make:347: test/cjportedtests.exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:411: test/CJUnitTestsPort/CMakeFiles/CJUnitTestsPort.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [makefile:124: all] Error 2

**Comment**

File which produces error at line 298 (marked as comment)

#### test/framework/test_asserts.cpp

```
void assertEquals(const sql::SQLString& expected, const char* result
                  , const char* file, int line)
{
  if (expected != result) // line 298. error here
  {
    std::stringstream errmsg;
    errmsg.str("");
    errmsg << "assertEquals(std::string) failed in" << file << ", line #" << line;
    errmsg << " expecting '" << expected << "' got '" << result << "'";
    TestsListener::testHasFailed(errmsg.str());
  }
}
```

sql::SQLString is defined in src/SQLString.cpp, which I think should be part of the libmariadbcpp.dll.a library. However after modifying the test/CJUnitTestsPort/CMakeLists.txt
to include

`SET(MY_TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES ${LIBRARY_NAME} C:/Libraries/mariadb/lib/libmariadbcpp.dll.a test_framework)`

it produces the same error.

I executed
build/test/driver_test.exe
build/test/static_test.exe
and got zero errors.

## Question

Why can the linker not find the reference here?

## Changes to original src/cmake files to make it work on mingw:

***When doing multiple changes in a single file, the line numbers represent the ones after the change before (from top to bottom)***

- delete libmariadb subfolder
- in CMakeLists.txt comment out lines: 524,525
- [src/CArrayImp.h:59-63] replace with just #define ZEROI64 0LL
- [src/CArray.cpp] comment lines 25-28
- [test/test_common.cpp:40-42] replace with #include <inttypes.h>
- [test/test_common.cpp:99-113] replace with

  - #define L64(x) x##LL
  - #define UL64(x) x##ULL
- [test/ccppTypes.h:41-49] replace with #include <string.h>
- [test/ccppTypes.h:64-78] replace with

  - #define L64(x) x##LL
  - #define UL64(x) x##ULL
- [test/unit/unit_fixture.cpp:37-43] replace with #define L64(x) x##LL
- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -IC:/directory/for/mariadb-connector_c/include -LC:/directory/for/mariadb-connector_c/lib
- CMAKE_C_FLAGS -IC:/directory/for/mariadb-connector_c/include -LC:/directory/for/mariadb-connector_c/lib
- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_STANDARD_LIBRARIES added -lsecur32 -lcrypt32 C:/path/to/ShLwApi.Lib

## EDIT in response to comments

#### SQLString.cpp

defines the != operator for the used case in test_asserts.cpp:

```
bool operator!=(const SQLString& str1, const char* str2)
{
    return str1.compare(0, str1.length(), str2, strlen(str2)) != 0;
}

bool operator!=(const char* str1, const SQLString& str2)
{
    return str2.compare(0, str2.length(), str1, strlen(str1)) != 0;
}
```

## Solution

a pull request has been issued on github.com (these changes might be unessecary in the future)

- [test/CJUnitTestsPort/CMakeLists.txt:35,41] change order of linking to ${LIBRARY_NAME} after test_framework
- [test/unit/CMakeLists.txt:31] change order of linking to ${LIBRARY_NAME} after test_framework
- [test/unit/example/CMakeLists.txt:48] change order of linking to ${LIBRARY_NAME} after test_framework
- [test/unit/classes/CMakeLists.txt:46,66,87,107,127,147,167,208] change order of linking to ${LIBRARY_NAME} after test_framework
- [test/unit/performance/CMakeLists.txt:45] change order of linking to ${LIBRARY_NAME} after test_framework
- [test/unit/bugs/CMakeLists.txt:45] change order of linking to ${LIBRARY_NAME} after test_framework

Comment: It looks like operator != could not be found. static_test and driver_test do  not use SQLString, and thus do not have those linking problem.

Comment: ${LIBRARY_NAME} in the SET(MY_TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES ${LIBRARY_NAME} test_framework) stands for C/C++ library target, and thus should make the test to link against built library. C:/Libraries/mariadb/lib/libmariadbcpp.dll.a is kinda redundant, whatever it is. Maybe the order of libraries matters here? What if move ${LIBRARY_NAME} after test_framework. Also I am not sure if WIN32 is true in cmake under mingw(to set MY_TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES correctly), but I guess you know better.

Comment: (see my edit in the question ) The operator is defined already, however the order of linking was the issue. I changed the order according to your comment and it worked. I had to do this for many of the test libraries. (edit of my question will include the solution)

Comment: Unfortunately I could not mark your response as the answer since it was a "comment", so I provided the answer myself.

Comment: I will survive low stackoverflow reputation :) Looks like you did quite a few changes to make it buildable on mingw. I don't think that mingw is supported by MariaDB, but if you make a pull request on the github with your changes, and if they do not break anything, they can be merged.

Comment: Could you please answer my question in the PR you submitted on Github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comment of Lawrin Novitsky, the solution to the problem is the order of linking. Question edited to include the solution as well.

## Solution

A pull request has been issued on github.com (these changes might be unessecary in the future)

- [test/CJUnitTestsPort/CMakeLists.txt:35,41] change order of linking to ${LIBRARY_NAME} after test_framework
- [test/unit/CMakeLists.txt:31] change order of linking to ${LIBRARY_NAME} after test_framework
- [test/unit/example/CMakeLists.txt:48] change order of linking to ${LIBRARY_NAME} after test_framework
- [test/unit/classes/CMakeLists.txt:46,66,87,107,127,147,167,208] change order of linking to ${LIBRARY_NAME} after test_framework
- [test/unit/performance/CMakeLists.txt:45] change order of linking to ${LIBRARY_NAME} after test_framework
- [test/unit/bugs/CMakeLists.txt:45] change order of linking to ${LIBRARY_NAME} after test_framework